# Solving this probability function

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

This is the probability of winning a game I calculated. It stands for the probability that playerX wins given he has a limit of x, and playerY has a limit of Y (the games involves picking a limit). If more information is needed on the context I can provide it. I would appreciate if someone could peer review my approach to see if it makes sense and where I'm making a mistake / how they would do it.

$$p(x,y)=p(\text{PlayerX  wins } | \text{ limitX} = x, \text{ limitY} = y)$$

$$p(x,y)=\frac{e^x(1-x)(1-e^y(1-y))+(\int_{max(x,y)}^{2}\int_{y}^{u}f_{U}(u)f_{V}(v)dvdu))e^x(1-x)e^y(1-y)}{1-(1-e^x(1-x))(1-e^y(1-y))}$$

Where : $$f_{U}(u)=\frac{min(1,u)-max(x,u-1)}{1-x}, x \leq u \leq 2$$

$$f_{V}(v)=\frac{min(1,v)-max(y,v-1)}{1-y}, y \leq v \leq 2$$

And, $0 \leq x,y \leq 1$

Now, I'm trying to find x $\forall y$ such that p(x,y) >= 0.5.

In other words, I'm trying to find the exact limit x that either wins or ties for all values of y.

To do this, I differentiate over x and integrate over y from 0 to x and use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule (edited):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}\int_{0}^{x}p(x,y))dy = p(x,x) + \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\partial p(x,y)}{\partial x}dy$$

The left part is just 0.5, since in this game the probability of winning if both have the same limit is 0.5. The right part I'm not sure where to start though.

Comment: Use `\min` and `\max` to get the right font and spacing for $\min$ and $\max$.

Comment: In the denominator of $p(x,y)$ should it be $1-e^y (1-y)$ rather than $1-e^x(1-y)$ ?

Comment: @JimB it should ! I just edited it, does that change your answer?

Comment: It changes it just a little bit (as the denominator is relatively constant).  But I'll modify my latest answer.

Comment: OK.  Updated the equations.  That makes things symmetric about the $x=y$ line.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**  In the previous version, I forgot to include the denominator but that has now been corrected below. I'm now also assuming that the denominator of $p(x,y)$ should have $1−e^y(1−y)$ rather than $1−e^x(1−y)$.

As a check on your final result (and especially if no analytic solution exists), constructing a contour plot of $p(x,y)$ should be essential. Here is an implementation in *Mathematica*.

```
fu[u_, x_] := (Min[1, u] - Max[x, u - 1])/(1 - x)
fv[v_, y_] := (Min[1, v] - Max[y, v - 1])/(1 - y)
p[x_, y_] := (Exp[x] (1 - x) (1 - Exp[y] (1 - y)) +
  NIntegrate[fu[u, x] fv[v, y], {u, Max[x, y], 2}, {v, y, u}] Exp[x] (1 - x) Exp[y] (1 - y))/
  (1 - (1 - Exp[x] (1 - x)) (1 - Exp[y] (1 - y)))

Show[ContourPlot[p[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ContourShading -> None, ContourLabels -> None,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18, Italic] &) /@ {"x", "y"},
  PlotLabel -> Style["p(x,y)", Bold, Italic, 24], Contours -> {0.5}, 
  ContourStyle -> Thickness[0.01]], 
 ContourPlot[p[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ContourShading -> None,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18, Italic, Black] &) /@ {"x", "y"},
  PlotLabel -> Style["p(x,y)", Bold, Italic, 24, Black], 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  ContourLabels -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, 
    Style[Text[
      Framed[z, Background -> White, FrameStyle -> White], {x, y}], 
     Bold, 14]]]]
```

[image: Contour plot of probability function]

The thick black contour is that of $p(x,y)=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

There is an explicit formula for $p(x,y)$ but only for special cases are there closed form solutions for $p(x,y)=1/2$.  However, one can use numerical methods on the simpler formula found below.

Using *Mathematica* one can expand the combinations associated with the $\min$ and $\max$ functions using boolean (i.e., indicator) functions:

```
fu[u_] := Boole[u <= 1] u + Boole[u > 1] - Boole[u <= x + 1] x - Boole[u > x + 1] (u - 1)
fv[v_] := Boole[v <= 1] v + Boole[v > 1] - Boole[v <= y + 1] y - Boole[v > y + 1] (v - 1)
terms = List @@ (fu[u] fv[v] // Expand)
(* {Boole[u > 1] Boole[v > 1], Boole[u > 1 + x] Boole[v > 1], -u Boole[u > 1 + x] Boole[v > 1], 
 Boole[u > 1] Boole[v > 1 + y], -v Boole[u > 1] Boole[v > 1 + y], 
 Boole[u > 1 + x] Boole[v > 1 + y], -u Boole[u > 1 + x] Boole[v > 1 + y], 
 -v Boole[u > 1 + x] Boole[v > 1 + y], u v Boole[u > 1 + x] Boole[v > 1 + y], 
 u Boole[v > 1] Boole[u <= 1], u Boole[v > 1 + y] Boole[u <= 1], 
 -u v Boole[v > 1 + y] Boole[u <= 1], -x Boole[v > 1] Boole[u <= 1 + x], 
 -x Boole[v > 1 + y] Boole[u <= 1 + x], v x Boole[v > 1 + y] Boole[u <= 1 + x],
 v Boole[u > 1] Boole[v <= 1], v Boole[u > 1 + x] Boole[v <= 1], 
 -u v Boole[u > 1 + x] Boole[v <= 1], u v Boole[u <= 1] Boole[v <= 1], 
 -v x Boole[u <= 1 + x] Boole[v <= 1], -y Boole[u > 1] Boole[v <= 1 + y], 
 -y Boole[u > 1 + x] Boole[v <= 1 + y], u y Boole[u > 1 + x] Boole[v <= 1 + y],
 -u y Boole[u <= 1] Boole[v <= 1 + y], x y Boole[u <= 1 + x] Boole[v <= 1 + y]} *)
```

Now we integrate each term separately and then add them up.  One set of equations is for when $x\geq y$ and the other for when $y\gt x$:

```
integralxGEy[x_, y_] = (Integrate[#, {u, x, 2}, {v, y, u}, 
       Assumptions -> 0 < y < x < 1] & /@ terms) // Total // FullSimplify
(* 1/12 (-1 + x) (-6 + x^3 - x^2 (1 + 2 y) + x (2 + y) (-2 + 3 y) + y (10 - y (3 + 2 y))) *)

integralyGTx[x_, y_] = (Integrate[#, {u, y, 2}, {v, y, u}, 
       Assumptions -> 0 < x < y < 1] & /@ terms) // Total // FullSimplify
(* 1/12 (-1 + y) (-6 + 2 x^3 - 3 x^2 (-1 + y) + 2 x (-1 + y)^2 + y (4 + y - y^2)) *)
```

Then those are plugged into a definition of $p(x,y)$:

```
p[x_, y_] := If[x >= y, (Exp[x] (1 - x) (1 - Exp[y] (1 - y)) + integralxGEy[x, y] Exp[x] Exp[y])/
  (1 - (1 - Exp[x] (1 - x)) (1 - Exp[y] (1 - y))),
  (Exp[x] (1 - x) (1 - Exp[y] (1 - y)) + integralyGTx[x, y] Exp[x] Exp[y])/
  (1 - (1 - Exp[x] (1 - x)) (1 - Exp[y] (1 - y)))]
```

So for $x\geq y$ we have for $p(x,y)$:

$$\frac{e^x (x-1) \left(e^y \left(-x^3+x^2-3 (x-1) y^2+2 (x-1)^2 y+4 x+2 y^3-6\right)+12\right)}{12 \left(\left(e^x (x-1)+1\right) e^y (y-1)+e^x (x-1)\right)}$$

and for $y>x$ we have

$$\frac{e^x \left(e^y (y-1) \left(-2 x^3+3 x^2 (y-1)-2 x ((y-2) y-5)+(y-3) (y (y+2)+2)\right)+12 (x-1)\right)}{12 \left(\left(e^x (x-1)+1\right) e^y (y-1)+e^x (x-1)\right)}$$

There is no closed form solution for $p(x,y)=1/2$ other than $p(x,x)=1/2$.  A contour plot of $p(x,y)$ follows:

```
ContourPlot[p[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, ContourShading -> None,
 Contours -> {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Thickness[0.001], Thickness[0.001], Thickness[0.001], Thickness[0.001],
   Thickness[0.01], Thickness[0.001]}, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 Frame -> True, ImageMargins -> 20, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18, Italic] &) /@ {"x", "y", " ", " "},
 PlotLabel -> Style["p(x,y)", Bold, Italic, 24], 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False,
 ContourLabels -> Function[{x, y, z}, Style[Text[Framed[z, Background -> White, FrameStyle -> White], {x, y}], Bold, 14]]]
```

[image: Contour plot of p(x,y)]

Comment: Thank you! Incredible answer. Little follow-up: is there a way to solve analytically or numerically for for that value that crosses the 0.5 line with the curve? I believe that would be the "optimal" limit for my context. From my simulations I believe it's around 0.4.

I tried differentiating over x then putting y = x, but that just gives 0.5.

Comment: By blowing up the section of the contour plot where the intersection is, it appears to be around 0.41619535.

Comment: I got the same answer by zooming in, do you think there’s a way to get an exact number by differentiating p(x,y) and setting x = y (since it’s the optimal both will be equal) or am I thinking about it wrong?

Comment: One can find the points $x$ and $y$ where $p(x,0)=1/2$ and $p(0,y)=1/2$ using a numeric root finding routine which gives $x=y=0.632808$.  There won't be a closed form solution as it involves finding $x$ where $-\frac{1}{12} e^x (x-1) \left(-x^3+x^2+4 x+6\right)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Hi Jim, could you clarify that last part? I feel like there should be a way to calculate the 0.41619 limit more precisely? Also not sure I understand where your last equation comes from.

Comment: The equation in my previous comment was the result of setting $y=0$.  Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Not exactly, I'm trying to find the limit where if x = limit, p(x,y) >= 1/2 for all values of y. Basically the optimal limit for my game (which is what I believe is the 0.41619 in the graphic).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144517/discussion-between-sushieater-and-jimb).